# How to reset all scope values in Angular Controller on Click?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to reset all the scope values in a controller. I searched they provide `$location` to redirect but i want to reset all the scope on ng-click.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are you trying to destroy the scope, or are you just trying to get rid of certain values? Here is a fiddle for clearing values if that's what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/009dyrc9/

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are trying to reset all controller scope values, you can do like the following:

```
angular.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  init();
  $scope.click = function() {
    init();
  } 
  function init() {
    $scope.foo = 'foo';
    $scope.bar = 'bar';
  }
})
```